# How can I add new fields from Power BI to existing PowerApps that's integrated using PowerBIIntegration?

Tags: powerbi, powerapps

My initial requirements was to create a PowerApp that's integrated with Power BI using one of the columns (say col1) from tables used in Power BI report. I implemented this and published the app.

Now, the requirements have changed and the request is for an additional column (say col2) in the same app. How can I add an additional new field that can somehow show under PowerBIIntegration.Data.col2?

I didn't find any documentation or reference for the same. In past, I have built PowerApps with multiple columns but not sure how to add new column to existing PowerApps when integrated with Power BI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, what you need to do is edit the power app from the PowerBI file or published version too.

Steps:

- Open the PowerBI file or the published file with clicking on edit
- Select your existing PowerApp visual
- Add the new columns by checking the new column check boxes per usual
- Then hover over the PowerApp Visual and click on on the three dots that appear in the top right of the powerApp visual, and select Edit,
- This will launch PowerApp studio page so you can edit the app

Using this method will also connect your app to the live data set from the PowerBIIntegration data set.

source text:

"If you change the data fields associated with the visual, you will need to edit the app from Power BI service to make sure that the changes are propagated to PowerApps. You will observe unexpected behavior if the app is not edited from Power BI service to make sure that the new fields from Power BI reflect in the app."

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/et-ee/blog/powerbi-powerapps-visual/